# C++ non class scope replacement for this.x = x;

Tags: c++, class, methods, this

In C++ I can do this in classes:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        int number;
        void SetNumber(int number);
};

void MyClass::SetNumber(int number)
{
    this->number = number;
}
```

But what about this:

```
int number;

void SetNumber(int number)
{
    //What do I do here?
}
```

This problem is because there isn't a "this" for the scope, there are only "this"s for classes. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really need to make a problem out of this?

Comment: Usually, using global variables is evil. So you can access them like NPE said, but maybe you shouldn't? I would suggest to think of a better way to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you are looking for

```
::number = number;
```

This assumes that the top `number` is declared at the global scope. If it isn't, we need more context.

Answer (score 2):

I think the very OBVIOUS solution is to NOT name the argument of a function the same as a global variable. Change either `number` to `aNumber` ("a" for "argument") or change `number` to `gNumber` ("g" for "global"). Or make the argument `num`, `n`, `nr`, `x`, `kerflunk` or anything other than `number`. [And this really applies to member functions too, in my opinion].